# "get lost" vs "got lost" in the current situation

Tags: phrase-choice

If I call my friend to ask how to get to their place, how is it better to say:

> I **get lost**. How can I get to your place?
>
> I **got lost**. How can I get to your place?

As I understand it, I can't say "I'm getting lost" in this case, can I?

Comment: I would use "I'm lost".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the three expressions can be used, with different meanings.

In the situation described, *I get lost* is a general statement. It means the same as this:
*I often get lost*, help me with directions.

*I got lost* means that you have already gotten lost on your way to your friends house.

*I'm getting lost* means that you may not be lost yet, but you are in danger of it.